# GCP - HTTPS and subdomains in different environments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

I currently have a GKE cluster and service set up at `app.companyname.com`. It lives in the `prod` GCP "project". I am now spinning up a `dev` project, and it's all good, except I don't know what to do with the domain name and certificate settings. I want the app available at `dev.companyname.com`

1. **Do I have a public DNS zone per project, or should I have one, in the prod enviromment that dev accesses somehow? Do they share nameserver settings? Does the prod project forward to the dev project?**
2. **Do I have a separate SSL certificates, one per environment? Or one in prod environment that dev accesses.**

**What is the general overview on how this should be set up with GCP?**

[image]

Comment: Some things should be clarified first. Is this a small project with the only two services exposed via External IP: "app" and "dev"? "1. Do I have a public DNS zone per project, or should I have one, in the prod enviromment" - where are you planning to host the public DNS zone: in an external DNS provider environment, in GCP (self-managed GCE instance, GKE pod, or managed Cloud DNS service)? Speaking about SSL certificates "2. ...one per environment ... Or one in prod environment", do you mean wildcard certificates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the question is about separation between Prod and Dev. Following this approach ("spinning up" a separate Dev project in GCP) you should stay consistent and separate public DNS as well. This will make projects scalable and align GCP service boundaries accordingly with the administration, trust, management and billing scopes managed by different teams.

**Do I have a public DNS zone per project?** - Broadly speaking, you should have a separate DNS zone **per environment** (but in the described case this means "per project"), in particular because [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_record) settings like `REFRESH` or `TTL` could be set different between Prod and Dev. Also, since each managed zone that you create is [associated](https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones#creating_managed_zones) with a Google Cloud project, you can leverage IAM [access control](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/access-control) features to stick with the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) in DNS zone management.

**Do they share nameserver settings?** - With a managed service such as Cloud DNS your projects will use name servers provided by vendor. You can find them in GCP Console or with `gcloud`:

```
$ gcloud config set core/project myworks-240610
 Updated property [core/project]. 
$ gcloud dns managed-zones list
 NAME      DNS_NAME              DESCRIPTION  VISIBILITY 
 my-works  myworks.example.com.               public 
$ gcloud dns managed-zones describe my-works --format="flattened(nameServers)" 
 nameServers[0]: ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com. 
 nameServers[1]: ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com. 
 nameServers[2]: ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com. 
 nameServers[3]: ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.  
$ dig ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com +short 
 216.239.32.107
```

NS address is **different** for different projects (that way between Prod and Dev). 
See [Updating your domain's name servers](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/update-name-servers)

**Do I have a separate SSL certificates, one per environment?** - In different DNS zones hosts will have different CNs, so you will have separate certificates in Prod and Dev. You can use [wildcard certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) to make things simpler, for example in Dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the specifics of GKE, but I can speak to general domain system.

Answers:

1. There is one DNS record for `companyname.com`, the `NS` records are set for the overall domain.  But there would be two `A` records, one for `prod` and one for `dev`. The `A` record points to the IP, so you can host them on any two servers, or the same one, or in a subdirectory of the other one, as long as Apache, or whatever serves the website, can match the full subdomain name to the directory in which the subdomain's files live
2. There are separate SSL certificates for each subdomain

Here is the example as the final DNS zone record to give you an idea of how to set your DNS settings:

```
; Name Servers
companyname.com.   IN   NS   ns1.somehost.com.
companyname.com.   IN   NS   ns2.somehost.com.
companyname.com.   IN   NS   ns3.somehost.com.

; A records 
@         IN   A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX       ; IP for the main companyname.com
prod      IN   A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX       ; IP for the app.companyname.com
dev       IN   A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX       ; IP for the dev.companyname.com
```

**About URLs**

A URL consists of protocol://Domain Name:port/path/file

```
https://prod.companyname.com:80/index.html
```

- Protocol is just http or https
- Domain name is what traverses the entire internet and the Domain Name Systems entire purpose is to map the domain name with the IP of the public facing server that holds that domain
- Just the port and hidden by the browser to the user
- The server then receives the request (something like Apache, or maybe GKE takes it from there) and maps the domain name to a root directory on the server, and then traverses down the path to the correct files to serve up to the requester

I know it is a lot to take in, but that is the root problem.  I can't speak to GKE and someone else might jump in and explain out it might be configured to do what you are doing.  But if you can get access to the DNS settings of the domain, and make a proper subdomain, this all gets a whole lot easier for you.

Comment: Thanks Katie. Hmm, bit to think about. So these A records, do they live in the prod GCP "project" presumably? I was hoping to have the prod project not have a DNS entry for dev. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry that I can't speak to GKE and someone else might be able to, but I added to my post about how URLs work, this is good information to understand when faced with the kind of configuration you are trying to achieve, hope it helps you make sense of the behavior (or maybe even settings in your environment to make it work)

Comment: That's alright. I'm looking for an answer to the question 1. specifically. I.e. how does the GCP project structure look like